# can't automatically update the total value of the textbox when pressing the delete key on the keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to sum all the values ​​are automatically entered in column 4 and displays it in the textbox .
i use this code :

```
private void totalAll()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++a)
    {
        b += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[3].Value);
    }
    textBox1.Text = b.ToString();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        totalAll();           
}
```

everything works but when I press the delete key on the keyboard , the total value of the textbox is not updated automatically. its value is not diminished .

[image: before delete]

[image]

Comment: What's the data source of your grid? There could be more elegant solutions when you use data-binding.

Comment: I use this grid only to process the data before it is saved to the database .

Comment: It's really better to use a model and use data-binding features. The model can be a plain Class in your application or a `DataTable`. Then showing data in grid and other controls and processing data would be really more easy and elegant.

Comment: I really beginner in using winforms . Thank you for your advice. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should recalculate the total value when a row is deleted from data grid view.

You should listen for the event when user has deleted a row
You should add this after `InitializedComponent();` in your form constructor.

```
dataGridView1.UserDeletedRow += (s, e) => totalAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try subscribe the dataGridView event RowsRemoved.
I didn't test this but should be something like:

```
dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += (s,e) => totalAll();
```

By the way, I think you can remove the foreach on the dataGridView1_CellEndEdit method, doesn't seem to do nothing